# How to integrate a simple ContentDialog in xaml? (C#)

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I dont quite understand how to make a simple ContentDialog. Basically I want to have a button that when pressed the ContentDialog Pops up. The ContentDialog should have at least 1 Button. I guess Im missing out something. I tried to put my part of the Code into it but there is an error when it Comes to build the program. My guess is that I still have to enter something in the XAML to make it work. This is the default Code of the .XAML (at the Bottom of the post you find the Code I want to put into it):

```
<Page
    x:Class="PDFViewerSDK_Win10.PDFReaderPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:PDFViewerSDK_Win10"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d" SizeChanged="OnSizeChanged">

    <Page.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="MenuItemTemplate">
            <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
                <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,0" Orientation="Vertical">
                    <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="{StaticResource ApplicationForegroundThemeBrush}" Width="300" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Title}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontFamily="Segoe UI"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Page.Resources>

    <Grid Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="68"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="0.35*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Canvas x:Name="mPDFView" Grid.RowSpan="3"/>
        <Canvas x:Name="mPDFThumb" Grid.Row="2" Visibility="Visible"/>
        <ListView x:Name="mMenuView"
                  Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                  VerticalAlignment="Top"
                  Margin="0, 68, 0, 0"
                  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MenuItemTemplate}"
                  IsItemClickEnabled="True"
                  ItemClick="OnMenuListItemClicked"
                  Visibility="Collapsed"
                  ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                  ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                  Grid.RowSpan="2"/>
        <Grid Height="68" Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="#7FC0C0C0" Grid.Row="0">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Column="0" Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Button x:Name="backButton" Click="OnBtnGoBack" IsEnabled="{Binding Frame.CanGoBack, ElementName=pageRoot}" Style="{StaticResource BackButtonStyle}" Margin="10,10,0,0" Foreground="Black" BorderBrush="Black" Background="Black" AllowDrop="True" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="-1.62,0.618"/>
                <Button x:Name="searchBtn" Style="{StaticResource AppBarButtonStyle}" Tapped="OnOptionItemTapped">
                    <Image Source="Assets/images/view_search.png"/>
                </Button>
                <Button x:Name="viewAnnotBtn" Style="{StaticResource AppBarButtonStyle}" Tapped="OnOptionItemTapped">
                    <Image Source="Assets/images/annot_line.png"/>
                </Button>
                <Button x:Name="doneAnnotBtn" Style="{StaticResource AppBarButtonStyle}" Tapped="OnOptionItemTapped" Visibility="Collapsed">
                    <Image Source="Assets/images/annot_done.png"/>
                </Button>
                <Button x:Name="removeAnnotBtn" Style="{StaticResource AppBarButtonStyle}" Tapped="OnOptionItemTapped" Visibility="Collapsed">
                    <Image Source="Assets/images/annot_remove.png"/>
                </Button>
                <Button x:Name="selectBtn" Style="{StaticResource AppBarButtonStyle}" Tapped="OnOptionItemTapped">
                    <!--Image Source="Assets/images/icon_select.png"/-->
                    <BitmapIcon Name="mSelectIcon" UriSource="ms-appx:///Assets/images/icon_select.png" />
                </Button>
                <Button x:Name="viewMenuBtn" Style="{StaticResource AppBarButtonStyle}" Tapped="OnOptionItemTapped">
                    <Image Source="Assets/images/icon_menu.png"/>
                </Button>
                <TextBox x:Name="mPageInput" Width="90"  Margin="30,10,5,10" FontSize="30" KeyDown="OnKeyDown"/>
                <TextBlock x:Name="mPageDisplay" Width="90" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="30" Margin="0,10,0,10"/>
                <Button x:Name="settingsBtn" Style="{StaticResource AppBarButtonStyle}" Tapped="OnOptionItemTapped">
                    <Image Source="Assets/images/icon_setting.png"/>
                </Button>
                <Button x:Name="thumbnailBtn" Style="{StaticResource AppBarButtonStyle}" Tapped="OnThumbItemTapped">
                    <Image Source="Assets/images/icon_thumbnail.png"/>
                </Button>
                    <Image Source="Assets/images/icon_menu.png"/>
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Right" Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Button x:Name="viewInfoBtn" Style="{StaticResource AppBarButtonStyle}" Tapped="OnOptionItemTapped">
                    <Image Source="Assets/images/view_about.png"/>
                </Button>

            </StackPanel>

        </Grid>

    </Grid>
    <Page.BottomAppBar>
        <AppBar x:Name="mAppBar">
            <Grid  x:Name="PDFOptionPanel"/>
        </AppBar>
    </Page.BottomAppBar>
</Page>
```

Now where do I have to put this part of the Code? Do I have to add something? What am I missing here?

```
        <ContentDialog x:Name="test" PrimaryButtonText="Ok" SecondaryButtonText="Cancel" Style="{StaticResource AppBarButtonStyle}" Tapped="OnOptionItemTapped" </ContentDialog>
```

Answer (score 2):

Derive from [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ContentDialog#remarks),

> Use a ContentDialog to request input from the user, or to show information in a modal dialog. You can add a ContentDialog to an app page using code or XAML, or you can create a custom dialog class that's derived from ContentDialog. Both ways are shown in the examples section of this topic.

There are many ways could integrate `ContentDialog` to page, If you just make a simple `ContentDialog`, you could implement it in code behind.

```
private async void DisplayNoWifiDialog()
{
    ContentDialog noWifiDialog = new ContentDialog()
    {
        Title = "No wifi connection",
        Content = "Check connection and try again.",
        CloseButtonText = "Ok"
    };

    await noWifiDialog.ShowAsync();
}
```

If you want implement it with xaml, please put your `ContentDialog` in the bottom of the root `Grid`. for example:

```
<Grid Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="This is ContentDialog"/>
    <Button Click="Button_Click" Content="ClickMe"/>
    <ContentDialog x:Name="test" PrimaryButtonText="Ok" SecondaryButtonText="Cancel"  Tapped="OnOptionItemTapped" ></ContentDialog>
</Grid>
```

Please note, the `ContentDialog` that you provided missed `>` end mark. For more info please refer [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.contentdialog).